# How can you prove that "if $f$ and $g$ are surjective functions, $g\circ f$ will be surjective"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

How can you prove that "if $f$ and $g$ are surjective functions, $g\circ f$ will be surjective"?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By applying the definition. There is not really any trick here.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75246/surjectivity-of-composition-of-surjective-functions
and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22572/injective-and-surjective-functions Maybe you can find some more among related links on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:A\longrightarrow B$ and $g:B\longrightarrow C$. Take $c\in C$. Since $g$  is surjective, there exists $b\in B$ such that $g(b)=c$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Putting together, you have $(g\circ f)(a)=c$. Since $c$ was arbitrary, you have the surjectivity.

Comment: -1 for stepping on Tobias' toes.