# Form a compositional identity function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

If we have two functions, $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ where $g(f(a))=a$ for every integer $a$, how do we satisfy these conditions so that $f$ and $g$ are not bijective?

Comment: The question is not really clear. Which conditions are you referring to?

Comment: It should not be that hard to find such an example. Similar example was given for N instead of Z in another your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82961/why-do-these-functions-have-to-be-bijective/82964#82964

Comment: I apologize for my ambiguity. What I mean to ask is: can we find functions $f$ and $g$ in which neither is bijective so that $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ where $g(f(a))=a$ for every integer $a$

Comment: @MartinSleziak: it seems much tougher to find examples for $\mathbb{Z}$ because of the difficulty of dealing with negative numbers. So far I have come up empty

Comment: What about taking the maps from that answer and extend them by putting $f(a)=g(a)=a$ for each $a\le 0$?

Comment: But if $f(a)=g(a)=a$ then we would have two bijective functions, which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @johnnymath:  Martin Sleziak's point was to use the function on $\mathbb{N}$ from Alon Amit's post, then extend it to negatives with the identity.  The section on $\mathbb{N}$ has already violated bijectivity.

Answer (score 4):

First, $f$ will have to be injective.  If $f$ is not injective then two integers $n$ and $m$, have $f(n)=f(m)$ and so $g(f(n))=g(f(m))$.  Similarly $g$ has to be surjective, or else for some $n$, $g(f(n))\neq n$.  But, $f$ can fail to be surjective and $g$ can fail to be injective.  Suppose that $f(n)=2n$ and $g(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ if $n$ is even and $g(n)=0$ if $n$ is odd.  Then $g(f(n))=n$.