# Surjectivity or Injectivity of combination of functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Are there any rules that apply to $f\circ g$ or $g\circ f$ 
if I know that $f$ is surjective but not injective,
and $g$ is also surjective but not injective?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are both surjective, then so are $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ (of course, the later one is redundant).

Comment: Moreover, if $g$ is not injective, then $f \circ g$ is not injective.

Comment: and if only f is surjective? does it necessarily mean that f∘g is not surjective ?

Comment: @Asaf: You can have $f\circ g$ surjective with $f$ surjective and $g$ not surjective.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75880/if-g-circ-f-is-the-identity-function-then-which-of-f-and-g-is-onto-and-w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$:

- If $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one, then $g\circ f$ is one-to-one.
- If $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is one-to-one and $g|_{f(A)}$ (the restriction of $g$ to the image of $f$) is one-to-one. But $g$ need not be one-to-one.
- Equivalently, if $f$ is *not* one-to-one, then $g\circ f$ is not one-to-one.
- If $f$ and $g$ are onto, then $g\circ f$ is onto.
- If $g\circ f$ is onto, then $g$ is onto, but $f$ need not be onto.
- Equivalently, if $g$ is not onto, then $g\circ f$ is not onto.
- If $f$ and $g$ are bijective, then $g\circ f$ is bijective.
- If $g\circ f$ is bijective, then $f$ is one-to-one, $g$ is onto, and $g|_{f(A)}$ is one-to-one, but that's the best you can say.

A standard example: take $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{x,y\}$, $C=\{2\}$. Take $f(1)=x$, $g(x)=g(y)=2$. Then $f$ is one-to-one and not onto; $g$ is onto and not one-to-one; and $g\circ f$ is bijective. 
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
   &   & y &  &\\
   &   &   &\searrow\\
1 & \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} & x & \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}& 2
\end{array}$$

If $g$ is onto and $f$ is not, then $g\circ f$ may or may not be onto. If $f$ is one-to-one and $g$ is not, then $g\circ f$ may or may not be one-to-one. I'll let you construct examples of each.