# Solving/Proving Composite Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Suppose *f* is a function from *X* to *Y* and *g* is a function from *Y* to *Z*. Prove the following:
*g* o *f* is one-to-one, then *f* is one-to-one.

How would I start such a problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the whole answer? If you don't, then don't click here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274914/show-that-if-g-circ-f-is-injective-then-so-is-f

Comment: That is practically like: "do not think of the pink elephant."