# Can $AA^T$ be a diagonal matrix for non-square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a $m \times n$ matrix $A$ where $m \gg n$. Can $AA^T$ be a diagonal matrix (meaning all the diagonal entries are non-zero and the off-diagonal entries are 0).

Comment: That's not what "diagonal matrix" means. Any matrix whose off-diagonal entries are zero is called a diagonal matrix. There is no requirement for the diagonal entries to be nonzero.

Comment: Case $vv^T$  where $v$ is a vector is the simplest to consider..

Answer (score 5):

No. Since $m \gg n$, there are many more rows than columns. We can let each row be a a vector in $n$ dimensional space. A diagonal matrix would only be produced if any distinct pair of vectors has a zero dot product, implying all vectors are perpendicular to each other, but since there are more vectors than the dimension this is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

$AA^T$ would be an $m\times m$ matrix of rank at most $n$, so with the requirement that

> all the diagonal entries are non-zero

the answer is no, as this requirement would give the matrix rank $m$. If you remove this requirement from your definition of "diagonal", however (which is customary), then the answer is yes. For instance the $0$ matrix.

One can even make it so that there are $n$ non-zero entries. In particular, if the top $n$ rows of $A$ makes an $n\times n$ identity matrix, and all entries below that are $0$, then $AA^T$ comes out to a diagonal matrix where the first $n$ diagonal entries are $1$, and the rest are $0$.

This can easily be tweaked to give any (positive) values you want along the diagonal. Since $AA^T$ is positive semi-definite, you can't get negative values along the diagonal.

Answer (score 4):

No, because $AA^T$ cannot have full rank.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true only because we chose $m>n$. Consider that any diagonal matrix is invertible (it will clearly have a non-zero determinant), and hence represents a sort of (linear) bijective map between two vector spaces. But we know that if the composition of two maps is bijective, then we know that [the first map must be injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274914/show-that-if-g-circ-f-is-injective-then-so-is-f?rq=1). We know from the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) that the linear map represented by matrix multiplication is injective (i.e., has a null kernel) if the rank of the matrix is equal to its dimension, but clearly an $m\times n$ matrix where $m>n$ has rank less than its dimension and is not injective, so $AA^T$ cannot be invertible.

As a bit of an aside, to see why this would be possible if $m<n$, consider the relatively trivial case of $1\times 2$ and its transpose $2\times 1$:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}1 \end{bmatrix}$

Clearly $AA^T = \begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}$ is trivially diagonal, whereas the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is rectangular.