# One of f and g has to be injective for g ◦ f to be injective. Is this a counter-example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

In this example that I have created, f and g are both surjective and total (total is a requirement for both f and g in this question) and the composite is bijective meaning it is injective. Is this a counter-example?

Context: Im studying cs first year in uk and one of the modules is discrete maths

Comment: You are messing up domains. To even write $g\circ f$ you would need the domain of $g$ to be the target of $f$. Even then, the question would be : "is $g\circ f$ injective" on the whole domain $\{A, B, E\}$. Is this making sense to you?

Comment: No but ill read it again and come back to your comment

Comment: Not a duplicate, but just for reference, some answers to the following question are proofs of the statement in the title: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1274914/139123

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to look a bit more thoroughly into exactly how $\circ$ works. I'm sure it could've worked the way you describe, but history and tradition has made it not work that way.

To be more explicit, in order for $g\circ f$ to *make sense*, the image of $f$ (some might even say the codomain) needs to be inside the domain of $g$. For instance, since $f(B)$ makes sense, we need $g(f(B))$ to make sense. Which is to say, $g(D)$ needs to exist. If $f(B)$ exists but $g(f(B))$ doesn't exist, then $g\circ f$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is not injective.  Then there exist some $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $x_1\neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

It follows then that $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$ and so by definition $(g\circ f)(x_1)=(g\circ f)(x_2)$ and therefore $(g\circ f)$ is also not injective.

That is to say, if $g\circ f$ is injective then $f$ must also be injective.