# Counterexample to $g \circ f$ one-to-one $\implies$ $g$, $f$ one-to-one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are functions.
If both $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one, then $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is one-to-one.

I believe the converse would be written: Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are functions. If $g \circ f: X \to Z$ is one-to-one, then both $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one.

I cannot come up with a counterexample and I believe the converse is also true. Any thoughts.

Comment: Counterexamples exist. To construct one, you could try and take $g$ to be something that is not one-to-one, but is one-to-one *if restricted to the range of $f$*. You can show though that $f$ must be one-to-one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76083/154545

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title, and include background to your question: Why do you think this is true? What possible (counter)examples have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x)=x^2$ and $f:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ defined by$f(x)=\sqrt x$. Then $g\circ f: \mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ is given by $(g\circ f)(x)=x$, that is injective, but $g$ is not injective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a singleton.

Then automatically $g\circ f:X\to Z$ and $f:X\to Y$ are one-to-one.

But there are no restrictions for function $g:Y\to Z$ except that its domain $Y$ is not empty.

E.g. you can let $Y$ have at least two elements and take $g$ constant.

Answer (score 0):

Below a visual counterexample showing that the injectivity ( " one-to-oneness") of the composite function:  *f o g*  does not imply the injectivity of both *f* ang *g*.

It also shows that the bijectivity of *f o g* does not even imply  *f* or *g* to be bijective.

In this counterexample, the composite function *f o g* is the identity function, **but this need absolutely not be the case.**   In the setZ below ( see diagram) , substitute a for c, c for b and b for a, and you obtain a new *f o g*  function that is not the identity function, but that is still one-to-one.

Note : making these substitutions in Z does not turn Z into a different set; for in a set as such there is no order, the "place" of elements does not count  : {a, b c} = {c,a,b} = Z

[image]